# Wrong rep change notification

Tags: bug, reputation, ios-app

Notification in the iOS app toolbar shows +5 rep, but in the list it’s showed as “(-5) User was removed”:

> [image: rep]

This looks odd.

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 11.0 (Build 15A372)